Implementing pagination using Astrojs and Strapi CMS
I'm trying to implement pagination in my Astro project, and am using Strapi as a backend.
I can control the pagination response by sending the needed items per page:

NOTE: I'm using SSR so I'm not using the getStaticPaths function and therefore can't use the inbuilt pagination function of Astro
My problem is that I couldn't change the values of the pages (pages numbers) in Astro. What is the correct way to navigate and change the current page number in Astro?
Data fetch function:
export const fetchArticles = async (page = 1, pageSize = 5, sort = 'createdAt:desc') => {
    const articles = await fetchApi<Article>({
        endpoint: 'articles',
        query: {
            populate: ['category', 'cover'].join(','),
            'pagination[page]': String(page),
            'pagination[pageSize]': String(pageSize),
            sort: sort
        }
    })
    return articles
}

Using the function:
const articles = await fetchArticles(currentPage, 5)
Navigation compoenent (currentPage is increased and that can be seen in the console log since it's a tsx component, but the value of the currentPage in the parent component doesn't change - meaning it doesn't update to the second page for fetching)
import { useState } from 'react'
interface Props {
    metaData: Pagination
    currentPage: number
}
export default function NewPagination(props: Props) {
    let { metaData, currentPage } = props

    const increaseCurrentPage = () => {
        currentPage++
        console.log(currentPage)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <nav className='text-center'>
                <ul className='inline-flex -space-x-px text-base h-10'>
                    <li>
                        <a className='flex items-center justify-center px-4 h-10 ms-0 leading-tight text-gray-500 bg-white border border-e-0 border-gray-300 rounded-s-lg hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white'>
                            Previous 
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>{currentPage}</li>

                    <li>
                        <a
                            onClick={increaseCurrentPage}
                            className='flex items-center justify-center px-4 h-10 leading-tight text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-e-lg hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white'
                        >
                            Next
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <script></script>
        </div>
    )
}

Clicking on "next" does't update the fetch parameter to fetch the second page of the results
Edit: The thing I need to know is how to update the currentPage value so it changes in the fetch function
index component:


---
import ListCategories from '@/components/ListCategories'
import ListPosts from '@/components/ListPosts'
import NewPagination from '@/components/NewPagination'
import TitlePage from '@/components/TitlePage'
import BaseLayout from '@/layouts/BaseLayout'
import Swiper from 'src/components/swiper/Swiper'
import { fetchArticles } from 'src/utils/fetchApiData'

let currentPage = 1

const articles = await fetchArticles(currentPage, 5)

const allArticles = articles.data.map((article) => article)
const swiperContent = allArticles.slice(0, 4)
// const metaData = articles.meta.pagination
---

<BaseLayout title=''>
    <Swiper client:load swiperContent={swiperContent} />
    <TitlePage title={'All Articles'} />

    <ListCategories />

    <ListPosts FirstBig={true} allArticles={allArticles} />
    <NewPagination />
</BaseLayout>

<script>
    import { animate } from 'motion'
    const showAnimations = localStorage.getItem('animations') === 'true'

    if (showAnimations) {
        animate(
            '.title',
            { y: [80, 0], opacity: [0, 1] },
            {
                duration: 2.5,
                opacity: { duration: 3 },

                offset: [0, 0.55, 0.75]
            }
        )
    }
</script>




It is unlucky that comments from Staging Ground were removed, I'll write again about rules of React and immutability of props/state and about the usage of setter from useState... But anyway, I think it would be better to add some details about how this component is used, how its props (and where) are declared and passed to this component for better picture... Or to remove the question completely if Author decided to use another approach using Astro components only, without React.

@SergeySosunov
My question is: how can I handle updating the state of a variable in Astro. I changed the tsx component into an Astro one - therefore I'm not using useState.
I will update the question and add the index component so you have the full picture of what I mean

The question currently says you're doing SSR, but in the staging ground comments you said you were doing SSG. which is it? either way, if you're using astro components, you can just create a plain old html link to the next page, and catch that as a route parameter. See https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/routing/

I was able to fix this by changing the pathname (using query params)
